# Not sure how to apply Poisson to a certain question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A blood bank is open for 2 hours every day, during which blood can be taken from a maximum of 70 blood donors. Experience shows that on average, 15% of the summoned donors do not appear at the blood bank. How many donors should be summoned so that the probability that at least 65 of them appear is at least 90%?

So I want to solve this using Poisson. I guess here we have $\lambda = 65 \times 0.85 \approx 55$. If we call $Y$ the amount of blood donors who appear, we want $P( Y \geq 65) = 0.9 \iff  P( Y \leq 64) = 0.1$. Is this correct, and if so, how do I calculate the value of this interval?

Comment: Strictly for integer values you have $P( Y \geq 65) \ge 0.9 \iff  P( Y \leq 64) \le 0.1$ .  If you end up with a normal approximation, it might be wise to use a continuity correction and have the boundary at about $64.5$

Comment: @Henry Indeed, edited it.

Comment: Even the Poisson is an approximation - the true distribution is binomial.